# Rails 3 - custom url in block not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use:

```
<% @deal.tasks.each do |task| %>
<li id="task_<%= task.id %>">
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
    <%= link_to "#{task.title}", deal_task_url(:id => task.id) %>  
</li>
<% end %>
```

in my routes...

```
match "tasks/:id" => "tasks#show", :as => "deal_task"
```

So the error i get is that task.id is nil, i can put task.id anywhere else in the block and it is the correct value, however when it's inside deal_task_url it is always nil.

Now, as a test to make sure my route worked, and was what I wanted, i did this...

```
<%= link_to "#{task.title}", deal_task_url(:id => '1') %>
```

It worked, but obviously every result had the same link.

So my question is 2 parts.

**Part 1 - Why doesn't this work**

deal_task_url(:id => task.id)

**Part 2 -**  - How would I get the task.id into the deal_task_url()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if you do `deal_task_url(task.id)`

Comment: I would like to know why it works when it's alone but if other arguments are present it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
deal_task_url(task.id)
```